# One real life object - two tables representing it?

Tags: mysql

This one is tricky for me. Please tell me which approach would be more effective.

I'm designing a table(s) representing real life places, mainly night clubs. I'm going to create such a place in the database, but if the owner of it wants an account in my system (to control the data used by my app) he can create one.

On the other side of the system I have users of my app, which will have access to some data concerning this place. They get the data no matter if there is an account for the owner of the place, or there's not.

Now, what I thought about, was creating two tables:

places (id, lng, lat, name, address...)

places_adm (id_from_places, username, pass, some_other_fields_with_owners_decisions)

When I only need data for the frontend user of the app, I take it from the places table. And when a place owner has an account, I present him the data from the two tables. With this approach I don't have any additional (and often empty) fields when dealing with frontend user, like password, which should make it faster for the user - and this is my priority. If the place owner creates an account, he has access to this data too, but he also has access to the second table. It's slower for the place owner than if I used one table,  but for the administration panel it's not that important.

The question is - would this approach make it faster (prioritizing the frontend user access), or should I "stick to the rules" and use one table and keep all the data in it, even if it's going to be empty in many cases and not used by the frontend user?

**EDIT:** To make it clear, ultimately the question is - Will a table with fewer fields perform significantly faster than a table with fields which won't be ever accessed by frontend user, but are specific for the "place" and important for the administration panel for the "owner of a place" (thus accessed rarely, so the performance won't be an issue in that case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question on SO (I had a problem to verbalise my needs).

[MySQL query performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805390/mysql-query-performance)

It appears, that in my case it would be better to make two seperate tables in terms of performance. Quassnoi says there, that adding a field into a table will make the queries which don't select it run slower, and those which do select it run faster. Obviously slower compared to situation when you don't have that particular field in the table and faster compared to situation when you join tables to retrieve that field.

It would mean, that keeping less important fields in a separate table would be a good practise. Especially when they are of dynamic format (varchar) - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/. I wonder if everyone agrees...

If it's wrong to answer my own question with help of another SO answer, please tell me, I'm new here.

Link to performance test thanks to bububaba.

Answer (score 1):

What if - at some point - you allow the place owner AND some if his trusted employees to admin the data? Will you add 3 columns to your table? Why 3? Maybe 10? :)

It seems more flexible to store the administrators separately (place_id, username, pass) and data concerning the place - separately.

Comment: Good point! But not precisely answering my question. I mean - still I'll have some data which will be accessed only from owners admin panel. And it will be place-specific, not admin-specific. But won't be important from the users point of view (frontend queries won't select this field at all).

Comment: Yeah... so am I right thinking that there are now 2 reasons to keep 2 separate tables (performance - as mentioned by you, flexibility - as mentioned by me) and 0 reasons to merge them into one? Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: I think you understood well. But it was the performance which it was really about so I was waiting for this answer to come. Thank you!

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that this will be of importance when performance is considered anyway. If you kept one table and had lots of unneeded columns, then you just wouldn't select them and save memory anyway.

Comment: Well, that is one of things I was thinking about. I wouldn't select them, but they would still be in the table. The question is if a SELECT on a table without these fields performs better than a select on a table containing them (but not selecting them). You say it's probably equal?

Comment: Most probably it's not equal. In fact there is some interesting insight here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/ . Still, you will probably hit one or two different performance bottlenecks before you should be concerned about the number of columns in your table.